# PHP/MySQL: Storing item ids

Tags: php, mysql, url

When I store some items in a table and then want to have a URL connected to each item I just have something like mywebsite.com/item/132
This will display info about the 132nd item in the items table. Is it bad to have it like this? Should I make it have something like youtube where there are a random set of characters for each item? What is the best way doing that?

Just store the items as usual numbers in the table and then a URL looks more like this?mywebsite.com/item/a19kgjy

Then a PHP script "decrypts" a19kgjy and gets a number which is used to get the correct item from the database?

Will this make everything much slower?

Comment: It will make it slower. The link 'mywebsite.com/item/132' is good enough....

Comment: @Oskwish What are these ITEMS you are referring to?

Comment: @itsols Products, things, videos whatever. It was just an example :P

Answer (score 2):

It's bad because you are adding extra work for the server to sort. Why not create a table something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    httpLink varchar(max)
)
```

in this case, you will only sort the `ID`

Comment: Okay, but is storing just ID with AUTO_INC (ofc ;) ) and then have URL's that include just the IDs as is?

Comment: Keep it simple - the first advice. DO not add those hashes you had in my in your question. I would suggest this kind of simple table (and add additional fields if needed of course) and if you don't like the IDs in the links or you want to be "seo friendly", you can have "slug" field (varchar type). Then when wadding new items, generate the slug, save it and then you can use those in the urls. Looks better - maybe, is this somehow logically different from having IDs in the URL - no :) Pick the one you like most, but do not add additional complexity to it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more related to a security/data protection question. It's really depends on whether you want it easily accessible by others or not. Sometimes the number is so sensitive where it's better to use the hash key, for example let's say transaction_id, or user_id, where you are exposing to others how many transaction your business having a day or how many users your system having, which could indirectly lead to some vulnerability. But if you want to implement the hash approach, I would recommend you to generate the random hash during the data insertion, rather than using the decryption approach during query. That would save you some processing power. But remember to index the hash field for the table. Anyhow, either a number or a hash is not really a search engine friendly url.